# how to put a image beside the text cause i want to put a image beside some text

Tags: html, css

here's my code someone please help me

Hey,I'm

```
<div style="font:normal normal bold 48px/1.4em roboto-thin,roboto,sans-serif;color:white;font-style: normal;">Mohammad</div>

<div style="font:normal normal bold 48px/1.4em roboto-thin,roboto,sans-serif;color:white;font-style: normal;">Shaib C. Dawood</div>
```

Comment: Could you explain where you want your image ? Beside the 2 divs ? On the right/left ? Etc.

Comment: pls give some more details about the problem